# Catch any of the errors in psycopg2 without listing them explicitly

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a `try` and `except` block where I would like to catch **only** the errors in the `psycopg2.errors` and not any other error.

The explicit way would be:

```
try:
    # execute a query
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_query)
except psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError, psycopg2.errors.GroupingError as err:
    # handle in case of error
```

The query will always be some SELECT statement. If the execution fails it should be handled. Any other exception not belonging to `psycopg`, e.g. like `ZeroDivisionError`, should not be caught from the `except` clause. However, I would like to avoid to list all errors after the `except` clause. In fact, if you list the psycopg errors, you get a quite extensive list:

```
from psycopg2 import errors
dir(errors)
```

I have searched quite extensively and am not sure if this question has been asked already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can you use the base class `psycopg2.Error` it catch all psycopg2 related errors

```
import psycopg2

try:
   cur = connection.cursor()
   cur.execute(sql_query)
except psycopg2.Error as err:
   # handle in case of error
```

see [official documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html?highlight=error#psycopg2.Error)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have implemented by catching a generic `Exception` and checking if the exception belongs to the list returned by `dir(errors)`. The solution proposed by Yannick looks simpler, though.

The function that I use prints the error details and checks using the name of the exception `err_type.__name__` whether it is in any of the psycopg `errors`:

```
from psycopg2 import errors

def is_psycopg2_exception(_err):
    err_type, err_obj, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print ("\npsycopg2 ERROR:", _err, "on line number:", traceback.tb_lineno)
    print ("psycopg2 traceback:", traceback, "-- type:", err_type)
    return err_type.__name__ in dir(errors)
```

Then, I use this function in the try/except clause:

```
try:
    # execute a query
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_query)
except Exception as err:
    if is_psycopg2_exception(err):
        # handle in case of psycopg error
    else:
        # other type of error
        sys.exit(1)  # quit
```

For my very specific case, where I need to check for other other exceptions as well, I can readapt Yannick solution as follows:

```
try:
    # execute a query
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_query)
except psycopg2.OperationalError as err:
    # handle some connection-related error
except psycopg2.Error as err:
    # handle in case of other psycopg error
except Exception as err:
    # any other error
    sys.exit(1)  # quit
```